# Dynamic Method, store return value in local

Tags: c#, dynamic, il

I am encountering some issues with a dynamic method. The (pseudo-)IL-Code for this method looks like this

```
var localB = dynMethodGen.DeclareLocal(typeof(Runtime.IntegerObject));
dynMethodGen.Emit(Ldc_I8, 2);
dynMethodGen.Emit(Newobj, Runtime.IntegerObject.Constructor);
dynMethodGen.Emit(ldstr, "a");
dynMethodGen.Emit(call, GlobalDeclaratorManager.SetMethod);
dynMethodGen.Emit(ldstr, "a");
dynMethodGen.Emit(call, GlobalDeclaratorManager.GetMethod);
dynMethodGen.Emit(Stloc, localB);
```

With this code i have the following problem: The final Stloc causes an exception:
System.Security.VerificationException: Dieser Vorgang kann die Laufzeit destabilisieren.
(In english it means the runtime could be destabilized).

I had this before when the stack was not correct but in this case the stack is correct. Replacing the Stloc in the end by a simple Pop everything works fine, except that the value is not stored in the locale.

The Get and Set methods look like that:

```
        public static GenericObject getGlobal(string name)
        {
            return mDeclarators[name];
        }

        public static void setGlobal(GenericObject value, string name)
        {
            mDeclarators[name] = value;
        }
```

What also works is replacing the Stloc with another call to SetMethod, the values are correctly passed along.

Am I missing some sort of restriction? Cant i store the return value of a function in a locale?

Comment: Have you tried creating an assembly with your method, saving that and running PEVerify on it? That usually gives a much better error message.

Comment: Good point! I will try that when i encounter the next problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is

```
setGlobal(new IntegerObject(2), "a");

IntegerObject localB = getGlobal("a");
```

where `getGlobal` is declared to return a `GenericObject` instance.

You can't store the reference to a `GenericObject` instance in an `IntegerObject` variable unless the `GenericObject` class extends the `IntegerObject` class. The C# compiler would give you the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'GenericObject' to 'IntegerObject'

Assuming `IntegerObject` extends `GenericObject`, the solution is to add a cast like

```
IntegerObject localB = (IntegerObject)getGlobal("a");
```

or

```
IntegerObject localB = getGlobal("a") as IntegerObject;
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought casting is only compile time like in C++ and will be done implicit. Works now perfectly!

Comment: If `IntegerObject` derives from `GenericObject`, then you can store an `IntegerObject` in a `GenericObject` variable without a cast. But since not all `GenericObject`s are `IntegerObject`s, you cannot store a `GenericObject` in a `IntegerObject` variable without a cast.